# Merge two list contained dictionary based on its index in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I have two list contain multi dictionary, each dictionary has a list as value, these are my list:

```
list1 = [{'a':[12,22,61],'b':[21,12,50]},{'c':[10,11,47],'d':[13,20,45],'e':[11,24,42]},{'a':[12,22,61],'b':[21,12,50]}]
list2 = [{'f':[21,23,51],'g':[11,12,44]},{'h':[22,26,68],'i':[12,9,65],'j':[10,12,50]},{'f':[21,23,51],'g':[11,12,44]}]
```

In my case, i need to merge these list with this rule:

1. Dictionary from the first list (list1) only can be merged by
   dictionary from the second list (list2) with the same listing index
2. After both of these list are merged, each dictionary has to be sorted based on the third number of its value

This is the expected result based on two rule above:

```
result = [
    {'a':[12,22,61],'f':[21,23,51],'b':[21,12,50],'g':[11,12,44]},
    {'h':[22,26,68],'i':[12,9,65],'j':[10,12,50],'c':[10,11,47],'d':[13,20,45],'e':[11,24,42]},
    {'a':[12,22,61],'f':[21,23,51],'b':[21,12,50],'g':[11,12,44]}
    ]
```

How can i do that? is it possible to be done in python with inline looping?

Comment: By "inline" looping, do you mean using comprehension constructs? Sure. Although, it could possibly be more clear using using for-statements. Have you tried anything?

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary, they are unordered by nature.

Comment: @iled good point. I originally though OP wanted the list values sorted.

Comment: Just to be sure: You are on Python 3.6? Otherwise you can't sort dictionaries. And even then it's tricky because you can only sort them by constructing them in the right order.

Comment: On older Python you could use the OrderedDict data type that comes with the standard library. But maybe you can find another data type that better fits your problem.

Comment: Your result is simple dictionary items additions.

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga, Paul Panzer, Siddhesh Mhatre for participating to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line (if you do not count with the import):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

[OrderedDict(sorted(dict(d1.items() + d2.items()).items(), key=lambda x: x[1][-1],
                    reverse=True)) for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2)]

[OrderedDict([('a', [12, 22, 61]),
              ('f', [21, 23, 51]),
              ('b', [21, 12, 50]),
              ('g', [11, 12, 44])]),
 OrderedDict([('h', [22, 26, 68]),
              ('i', [12, 9, 65]),
              ('j', [10, 12, 50]),
              ('c', [10, 11, 47]),
              ('d', [13, 20, 45]),
              ('e', [11, 24, 42])]),
 OrderedDict([('a', [12, 22, 61]),
              ('f', [21, 23, 51]),
              ('b', [21, 12, 50]),
              ('g', [11, 12, 44])])]
```

This works in Python 2.7.

Comment: @Faizalprbw yw! Let me know if there is any part that may require explanation. Also, you may find the related questions very useful, e.g., [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python).

Comment: Actually, this is the very simple example of my problem, i have big json data contains the same structure as that.. But you're example is working, now i'm trying to understand you're syntax myself, if i'm stuck, i'll ask you.. Thank you very much.. @iled

Comment: Sure. Basically there are two major questions here: 1. Merge dictionaries; 2. Sort dictionaries. For the first part, you may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/3079302) very useful. For the second, see the link in my previous comment. The syntax used to wrap these things is a list comprehension and a [lambda function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful/890188#890188).

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for python 3 and the result no longer contains dictionaries, and using an `OrderedDict` does not change anything in this case.

Comment: @StevenSummers Thank you, I had `sorted` and `OrderedDict` in the wrong order. I am not using Python 3, sorry for not specifying that in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
[dict(a, **b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct, see the second requirement of the OP: *After both of these list are merged, each dictionary has to be sorted based on the third number of its value*

Comment: As someone mentioned in the comments below your question, it is not possible to sort (order elements of) a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, `someone == iled`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad! Didn't see your name.

Comment: It's possible now (CPython 3.6+)

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not sorted by nature, so if you don't need them sorted your can merge them in a simple one-liner.

```
result = [ {**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2) ] # python 3.5+
```

If you are using a lower version then define a merge function.

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    result = d1.copy()
    result.update(d2)
    return result
```

And then have

```
result = [ merge(d1, d2) for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2) ]
```

If you do need them sorted then your only option is to use an OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def merge(d1, d2):
    tempD = d1.copy()
    tempD.update(d2)
    return OrderedDict(sorted(tempD.items(), key = lambda t: t[1][2], reverse = True))

result = [ merge(d1, d2) for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2) ]
```

Or even shorter for python 3.5+ is

```
result = [ OrderedDict(sorted(({**d1, **d2}).items(), key = lambda t: t[1][2], reverse = True)) for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2) ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this for your result :

```
r = map(lambda x,y:dict(x.items() + y.items()), list1, list2)
```

Result :

```
[{'a': [12, 22, 61], 'b': [21, 12, 50], 'g': [11, 12, 44], 'f': [21, 23, 51]},
 {'c': [10, 11, 47], 'e': [11, 24, 42], 'd': [13, 20, 45], 'i': [12, 9, 65], 'h': [22, 26, 68], 'j': [10, 12, 50]},
 {'a': [12, 22, 61], 'b': [21, 12, 50], 'g': [11, 12, 44], 'f': [21, 23, 51]}]
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct, see the second requirement of the OP: *After both of these list are merged, each dictionary has to be sorted based on the third number of its value*

Comment: Yup trying for 2nd requirement  sorted data.

Comment: @iled +1 for your answer.