# how to add a dictionary item from one list to the other dictionary in other list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one list of dictionary like this:

```
data = [{"name":"Kane", "age": 29},
        {"name":"will", "age": "32"}]


dtat_2 = [ {"Team":"SRH", "Country" :"NZ"},
           {"Team":"RCB", "Country" :"WI"}]
```

Expected output:

```
data3 = [{"name":"Kane", "age": 29, "Team":"SRH", "Country" :"NZ"},
         {"name":"will", "age": "32", "Team":"RCB", "Country" :"WI"}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two list contained dictionary based on its index in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311288/merge-two-list-contained-dictionary-based-on-its-index-in-python)

Comment: Do you mean sql-like ```join```? I.e. can it happen, that e.g. data will have more elements, with at least 2 refering to one and the same element from ```dtat_2```?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On python >= 3.5 you can zip the lists and unpack them like this:

```
[{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(data, dtat_2)]
# [{'Country': 'NZ', 'Team': 'SRH', 'age': 29, 'name': 'Kane'},
#  {'Country': 'WI', 'Team': 'RCB', 'age': '32', 'name': 'will'}]
```

---

Another one that should work for any version is in-place update, this updates one of the dictionaries (just fyi).

```
for d1, d2 in zip(data, dtat_2):
    d1.update(d2)

data
# [{'Country': 'NZ', 'Team': 'SRH', 'age': 29, 'name': 'Kane'},
#  {'Country': 'WI', 'Team': 'RCB', 'age': '32', 'name': 'will'}]
```